# How to structute the data properly in firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working in a React + Firebase project. In Firestore I need to save the data of users, but currently I don't know which approach to use.
There will be two users, Teacher and Student.

1st option: Set a collection of users, each document will have the 'user-type' field which defines if a user is a Teacher or a student. The problem that I saw with this approach is, lets say:

- A teacher enter his credentials and tries to log in. After the successful log in, my system will go to firestore and search for the information related to the teacher. So basically in will query the 'users' collection to find data based on the email (email will be unique) and the 'user-type' == 'teacher'. **In the worst case, users is a really big collection and then the query to get the data of the teacher will impact the UX, since firestore needs to read a considerable amount of documents.**

2nd option: Create two collections, a collection of 'teachers' and a collection of 'students'. Then in my system, instead of having a single login button, I will set two login buttons, one to login as a teacher and one to login as a student. Then, for the same example:

- A teacher enter his credentials and tries to log in. After successful log in, my system will go to firestore and search for the information in the 'teachers' collection, being very fast retrieving the data I need. **The problem here is the fact that I need to build two buttons, and I'm affraid of it to make my web application not very user-friendly or less intuitive.**

Hope I explained myself well, I'm not the best english writter and google translate isn't helping too much.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So basically in will query the 'users' collection to find data based on the email (email will be unique) and the 'user-type' == 'teacher'

that is not true. If emails are really unique, you don't need to filter by `user-type`. You don't need to use `where`. Just create a reference to the document associated with the user and `get()` it:

```
const userDoc = await db.collection('users').doc(userEmail).get();
```

As Nicholas said, you should consider using the UID instead of the email.

> users is a really big collection and then the query to get the data of the teacher will impact the UX, since firestore needs to read a considerable amount of documents

that is also not true. [Query performance is proportional to the size of your result set, not your data set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore#querying) .

Regarding Nicholas Tower answer,

> If you have two .where clauses like this, i think you'll need to create an index. The code should throw an exception which has a url; follow that url, and it will let you create the index (and once its created, the exception doesn't happen any more).

you only need an index if you combine equalities (`==`) with ranges (`>`, `>=` etc). You can combine as many `==` as you like without an index.

Comment: I thought firebase read all documents and then return those who match criteria. So if I had a collection of 10,000 users and I ask firestore to give me just X user, it wouldn't take a lot of time for firestore to give me the query result?

Comment: @HenryPeregrino No, it doesn't work like that. It's much better. See https://youtu.be/Ofux_4c94FI?t=558

Comment: Excelent. Thanks for helping me, now I have a better understand of how firestore queries work!